# Oracle SQL query: Best way to remove unwanted characters?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I want to remove all characters that are neither underscore, hyphen or alpha-numeric. Additionally, I don't want underscore or hyphen as the first character, so that needs to be removed as well.

This seems to mostly work using [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions149.htm#SQLRF06302) and LTRIM:

```
SELECT LTRIM(
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    '_-Hello(-)World)', 
    '[^-^_^a-z^A-Z^0-9]*', 
    ''),
  '_-') AS "result" 
FROM dual;
```

This correctly returns:

```
result
--------------------
Hello-World
```

However, for some reason this doesn't quite work when there is a line-break in the source string:

```
SELECT LTRIM(
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    '_-Hello(-
)World)', 
    '[^-^_^a-z^A-Z^0-9]*', 
    ''),
  '_-') AS "result"
FROM dual;
```

This instead returns "HelloWorld", i.e. without the hyphen:

```
result
--------------------
HelloWorld
```

There may be other issues with this solution as well that I have forgotten to mention. So, is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'[^-^_^a-z^A-Z^0-9]*'
```

selects zero or more characters that are not (first circumflex) a hyphen, circumflex (second), underscore, circumflex (...), a to z, circumflex (...), A to Z, circumflex (to be sure) or zero to nine.  So if you were to test with a text containing a circumflex (not on top of a vowel), it would surely remain, since you insist numerous times.

Also, if you'd happen to be using SQL*Plus, an interesting feature is the line continuation character, "-" or hyphen.

```
SQL> select 'multiple -
> lines' from dual;

'MULTIPLELINES'
---------------
multiple  lines
```

Perhaps read [Continuing a Long SQL*Plus Command on Additional Lines](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b12170/ch5.htm). It explains about the disappearing hyphen.